# Real-time sound transformation in Python using LADSPA and/or VST plugins

Tags: python, audio

I am looking for a way to capture audio from a mic, transform it using a LADSPA/VST plugin, and publish the resulting sound as a stream available in IP network. The type of filter applied and its parameters should be controlled via Python.

I am aware this is pretty many layered question, but the real-time sound processing in Python is terra incognita for me, so I am clutching at straws here, even at how to architect this solution.